# How can i find a two points of triangle from a point and a center of gravity in a 3D

Tags: matlab, math

Using Matlab, how can I calculate a two points in Equilateral triangle if there are known one point and the Center of Gravity in a 3D ?
I know there is a infinite solutions but i need just  a random one.
Thank you.

Comment: How does 3D come into play? A triangle is two dimensional.

Comment: @aioobe I believe Eli means creating a 2D triangle in a 3D space.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free programming service. I've given you an outline of the process mathematically. Please try to implement it. If you have specific difficulties you can return and show what you've tried and ask for help in a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the vector pointing from the center of gravity to the point.
Create an orthogonal vector (this can be done in a few ways, I usually take the first vector, add 1.0 to each component until it is not parallel, then take the cross product with the original vector).

Rotate your vector 120 degrees about the orthogonal vector. (look up the rotation matrix about an arbitrary vector)

Create your second point by adding that vector to your center of gravity.

Create your third point by rotating it again or in the opposite direction.

Comment: @rayryeng - Just i want to know if 60 or 120 degees  and yes thank you Christian for the help ;)

Comment: Yes of course, 120 degrees. I've modified the answer. It's also polite to accept an answer if you believe it is technically correct. Good luck with the implementation. If you have any further questions you can create another post and let me know by commenting here again.